# RDS is not connecting with ECS Fargate through secret manager

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, aws-secrets-manager

I am facing an issue with my Laravel application deployment on AWS ECS. The deployment process involves Jenkins, AWS ECR, and ECS. The new task is created, but there's an "Access Denied" error connecting to the RDS database.

I have created an RDS instance and saved the username and password into the Secret Manager. I have used Secret Manager keys into ECS Task Definition in Environment variable as ValueFrom like this

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:794664117291:secret:product-management-secrets-83qahw::username:
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:794664117291:secret:product-management-secrets-83qahw::password:
```

and Engine, Host, and Port I have added in .env.example file that I'm copying into Dockerfile.

I have also checked with `SSH` into ECS Task and did check that `.env.example` is copying into `.env` but the issue is that why ECS is not getting secret manager environment variable and due to that coming Access Denied issue and ECS getting default database `forge` from `config/database.php`

I've been very confused and trying for the last 3 days but I'm unable to solve this issue.

Please let me know if you will need further information. i will provide you. Thanks